# Remove INFO logs from scrapy.middleware and scrapy.crawler

Tags: python, logging, scrapy, screen-scraping

Does anyone know if there is a way to set different levels for scrapy's modules ? I want to log scraped item and the requests sent in a log file, but the logs coming from the *scrapy.middleware*, *scrapy.crawler* and *scrapy.utils.log* modules are always the same and do not add value to the log file.

My biggest constraint is that I have to do everything outside of the spiders (in the pipelines, the settings.py file, etc.). I have more than 200 spiders and cannot possibly add code to each of them.

Scrapy's doc says it is possible to modify the level for a specific logger in the [advanced customization section](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#advanced-customization), but it does not seem to work when this is set in the settings.py file. My guess is that the logs from scrapy.middleware and scrapy.crawler are logged *before* the spider evaluates the settings.py file.

I have read scrapy's doc extensively but I cannot seem to find the answer. I don't want to have to recreate my own loggers since *some* of Scrapy's logs are useful, like the ones logging requests sent and errors.

I can provide code extracts if necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scrapy extension that manipulates the various log levels setting them to higher values for the ones you do not want to appear.  The first 3 logs that come from `scrapy.utils.log` are run before scrapy get's to loading it's extensions, so those 3 I am not sure what to do beyond turning logging off entirely and implementing the logs yourself.

Here is an example of the extension:

`extension.py`

```py
import logging
from scrapy.exceptions import NotConfigured
from scrapy import signals
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CustomLogExtension:

    def __init__(self):
        self.level = logging.WARNING
        self.modules = ['scrapy.utils.log', 'scrapy.middleware',
                        'scrapy.extensions.logstats', 'scrapy.statscollectors', 
                        'scrapy.core.engine', 'scrapy.core.scraper', 
                        'scrapy.crawler', 'scrapy.extensions', 
                        __name__]
        for module in self.modules:
            logger = logging.getLogger(module)
            logger.setLevel(self.level)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        if not crawler.settings.getbool('CUSTOM_LOG_EXTENSION'):
            raise NotConfigured
        ext = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(
            ext.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened
        )
        return ext

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        logger.debug("This log should not appear.")
```

Then in your `settings.py`

`settings.py`

```py
CUSTOM_LOG_EXTENSION = True
EXTENSIONS = {
   'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
   'my_project_name.extension.CustomLogExtension': 1,
}
```

The example above removes pretty much all of the logs produced by scrapy.  If you only want to keep the request logs, then just remove `scrapy.core.engine` from the `self.modules` list in the Extension constructor.

Comment: This looks like what I needed ! I didn't think about using extensions. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me, I created the extension.py and added the settings and changed my_project_name to mine: [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED': True,
 'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
 'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 1,
 'AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY': 2,